# Disallow purchase if coupon code is not entered?

Tags: 6, ubercart

I have a product that is part of a Groupon-like promotion. The customer purchases a promo code at the Groupon-like website and those coupon codes are entered into my Ubercart system as 100%-off discounts. I want to only allow this particular product to be purchased when one of those specific codes has been entered into the cart. In other words, the credit card entry panel would not appear until they have entered a valid code for that product's promotion.

Is that possible? If so, how might I accomplish that? Rules/Conditional Actions?

Thanks!

Comment: Which coupon module are you using?

Comment: I am using UC Discounts Alternative: https://drupal.org/project/uc_discounts_alt

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this sadly, your best bet would be to try and play around with `hook_form_validate` or `hook_form_submit` on the ubercart form submit and see if you can find the field values in one of the submitted panes.

If that doesn't work then your best bet would be to try and code your own "pre review order" coupon box, that hooks into the cart view page. So what I am thinking is

- Users goes to /cart
- Has the listing of the items in the cart
- Has the "coupon stuff" at the buttom, but part of the "Checkout" form (use
  `form_alter` for example)
- And use the `hook_form_validate` hook to verify it has data, and the coupon is good, then proceed

Comment: OK, that's a good idea. I will take a look at it from that angle. Thanks!